# How to write an insert query in HQL for a class containing components?

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I am trying to write an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` query in HQL. However, the class I am inserting contains `<component>` items in the mapping. For example, my class definition could be:

```
public class X
{
    public virtual string A { get; set; }
    public virtual string B { get; set; }
    public virtual Y C { get; set; }
}
public class Y
{
    public virtual string C1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string C2 { get; set; }
}
```

And a possible mapping:

```
<class name="X">
    <id type="int"><generator class="identity"/></id>
    <property name="A" />
    <property name="B" />
        <component name="C">
            <property name="C1" column="C1" />
            <property name="C2" column="C2" />
        </component>
    </component>
</class>
```

How do I write an insert query for this class in HQL? I tried:

```
session.CreateQuery("INSERT INTO X(A, B, C1, C2) SELECT A, B, 'foo', 'bar' FROM X data")
       .ExecuteUpdate();
```

This gives the error:

```
NHibernate.QueryException : could not resolve property: C1 of: X
[INSERT INTO X(A, B, C1, C2) SELECT A, B, "foo", "bar" FROM X data]
```

I also tried:

```
session.CreateQuery("INSERT INTO X(A, B, C) SELECT A, B, :C FROM X data")
       .SetParameter("C", new Y() { C1 = "foo", C2 = "bar" });
       .ExecuteUpdate();
```

This gives the error:

```
NHibernate.HibernateException : Could not determine a type for class: Y
```

I also tried:

```
session.CreateQuery("INSERT INTO X(A, B, C.C1, C.C2) SELECT A, B, 'foo', 'bar' FROM X data")
       .ExecuteUpdate();
```

This gives the error:

```
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException : Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.MismatchedTreeNodeException' was thrown. near line 1, column 21 
[INSERT INTO X(A, B, C.C1, C.C2) SELECT A, B, "foo", "bar" FROM X data]
```

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("INSERT INTO X(A, B, C1, C2) SELECT A, B, 'foo', 'bar' FROM X data")
       .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Comment: Well, this is executing plain SQL via NH, this is not HQL.

Answer (score 2):

HQL is about retrieving entities, not about retrieving records or inserting records.

When using NHibernate, you should not think in terms of records and recordsets, but in terms of entities.
So, if you want to insert something in the DB using NHibernate, you'll have to create an instance of an entity, and Save that entity to the database using NHibernate's ISession.

Comment: So if my database contains 1000 items which I want to copy, I need to retrieve 1000 items and insert them again instead of using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`?

Comment: Such things shouldn't be done with NHibernate, but with plain SQL.  NHibernate is usefull, but it is not a silver bullet that can be used for every problem.  (Keep in mind that you can execute plain SQL via NHibernate as well)

Answer (score 1):

As Frederik Gheysels already answered, you should create and save new entities through an NHibernate session object.  If you're inserting a lot of entities, I would recommend using a stateless session object to speed things up a little.

```
using (IStatelessSession statelessSession = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
using (ITransaction transaction = statelessSession.BeginTransaction())
{
    foreach (var entity in entities)
        statelessSession.Insert(entity);

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

It may not be a measurable improvement, depending on how much data you insert. In my current project I can bulk insert around 16000 entities in less than a second using stateless sessions.